# Dropbox Error DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/files/sandbox

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox

I have integrated Dropbox core api. I am able to upload data without any error but when i am downloading all contents present in my app folder its showing the following error :

> DropboxSDK: error making request to
>   /1/files/sandbox/Mov_1373955204.txt - Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1001 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain
>   error -1001.)" UserInfo=0x9c0ec30 {path=/Mov_1373955204.txt,
>   destinationPath=/Users/mac26/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/6.0/Applications/800506EB-02E2-40F6-8B2B-F8B296760795/Library/Caches/DropBox/Mov_1373955204.txt}

I have searched alot have also tried to change the request timeout from 20 to 200 but still same issue is coming. 
Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=68501#post-470366 and https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=47676#post-364940 might be helpful

Comment: can you please post the code used to download files..?

Comment: I also have this issue,.. If you overcome from this issue please tell me,.. Thanks with advance

Comment: @Bala the link no longer works. Can you update it?

Comment: Dhara, did you solve this ?